# Windows 2008 - Remove Windows User Remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008

On a Windows 2008 server, how to remove an user from Admin group. Below command works on local machine, say A

```
net localgroup administrators "Domain\username" /delete
```

what i require is a windows command, to do the same on another server B, from Server A,instead of logging into each server manually and running command.

I am not windows admin, so dont have access to win admin tools.

Comment: The reason for different teams within a service desk is not to limit the tools you can use, but to ensure work is done by the people responsible for a system.  Get the windows admin who you aren't to do it.

Comment: If you aren't the windows admin, you won't have the rights to do this anyway..

Answer (score 2):

With PowerShell 2.0 and newer, you can use [`Invoke-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719(v=wps.620).aspx) against a remote computer:

```
$cmd = {.\cmd.exe /c net use localgroup Administrators "Domain\username" delete}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverB -ScriptBlock $cmd
```

Alternatively, you can download [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and use it to run the command on serverB:

```
psexec \\serverB -u adminUser net localgroup Administrators "Domain\username" /delete
```

`adminUser` should be a member of the `Administrators` group on serverB
You'll be prompted for the password when you hit enter. You can specify `-p P@$$w0rd!` if you need it for scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `psexec` from sysinternals, or PowerShell remoting to run this command remotely. Alternatively, you can use Group Policy Preferences to centrally manage local group membership.

Comment: Thanks. is there no windows command? I did find some scripts using psexec and powershell, but since i am not knowlegeable on both, am looking at win command, which I am comfortable with.

Comment: No, there isn't. You'll need to learn something new like how to use psexec or PowerShell.